# How to disable OnClick event on Spinner automatically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

**My code is:**

```
spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        }
    );
```

**I have implemented setSelectedItem in spinner as:**

```
spin2.setSelection(new Date().getMonth());
```

I want toast to be displayed when item is selected. It should not be displayed automatically.

Comment: spin2.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `Toast` is not automatically displayed.

You are using `spin2.setSelection(new Date().getMonth());` to select item programatically.
so whenever this line executes `OnItemSelectedListener` will be called.

To get rid of this you should use some flag(boolean variable).

something like this

```
//set flag to false before selection
spin2.setSelection(new Date().getMonth());


spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
            int position, long id) {
         if(flag is true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }else{
                 //then set flag to true here
             }
        }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    }
);
```